# Autofill without using select

Tags: excel, vba

Im quite new to VBA, and I know this is probably a silly question, but how do I autofill a set of cells.

I tried recording a macro and testing it out and this is what I got, but I know using select in VBA is not supposed to be great. Can anyone help :)

```
Range("E13:E17").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E13:E28"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: ```Range("E13:E17").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E13:E28"), Type:=xlFillDefault```

Comment: Can this be done using `Cells` as well? Like knowing the destination of the first and last cell and then wanting it to fill inbetween as well

Comment: You can use cells in range. ```range(cells(13, 5),cells(17,5))```